# ¿Cómo puedo saber si un número es múltiplo de 50 en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

He hecho un botón el cual cuando lo pulsas sube un número en una pantalla.

Ahora quiero que cuando sea múltiplo de 50 se haga display un gif.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a hacer la condición "if" que comprobará si el numero es múltiplo de 50?

```js
numero = 1204040 ;  //variable numero 
            
if ( numero ==  ){
  document.getElementById(gif).innerHTML.display = inline ; //Aquí se hace display el gif
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Preguntas si el resto de la división es cero, lo cual quiere decir que es múltiplo.

```js
var numero = 1204000 ;  
var resto = numero % 50;   
    if ( resto == 0 ){
      alert("multiplo");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
numero = 1204040 ;  //variable numero            
if ( numero%50==0){
  document.getElementById(gif).innerHTML.display = inline ; //Aqui se hace display el gif
}
```