# ¿Cómo validar si un número es múltiplo de 5?

Tags: javascript, html5

Necesito un programa que le pida al usuario un número e imprima si es un múltiplo de 5 o no.

De momento he hecho esto:

```
let numero = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un numero por favor: "));

if (numero % 5){
    console.log("Si, el número "+numero+ " es múltiplo de 5");
}else{
    console.log("No, el número "+numero+ " no es múltiplo de 5");
}
```

Pero no me funciona.

Comment: Sugerencia: Sé más específico en los errores o problemas. "No me funciona" hace difícil saber el problema que tienes con el código que muestras.

Comment: No entiendo los puntos a favor de esta pregunta si es algo que realmente no es cosa del otro mundo y seguramente se ha hablado en muchísimos foros o incluso aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/188350/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-saber-si-un-n%C3%BAmero-es-m%C3%BAltiplo-de-50-en-javascript

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo puedo saber si un número es múltiplo de 50 en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/188350/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-saber-si-un-n%c3%bamero-es-m%c3%baltiplo-de-50-en-javascript)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Te falta hacer la comparación en tu sentencia `if`, es decir:
Si el residuo de la división es  `==` a cero

```js
let numero = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un numero por favor:")); //capturamos el valor

     if ( numero > 0 && numero % 5 == 0 ) { //hacemos la comparación
         console.log("Si, el número "+numero+ " es múltiplo de 5"  )
     }else{
       console.log("No, el número "+numero+ " no es múltiplo de 5");

      }
```

Comment: Una pregunta: _¿`0` es múltiplo de `5`?_

Comment: @A.Cedano tienes toda la razon. 0 daria verdadero, edite la respuesta

Comment: La cuestión es que no sé realmente si `0` es múltiplo de todos los números o no, por eso pregunto.

Comment: @A.Cedano teoricamente no, por lo menos, en Java cuando divides un numero entero por 0 te lanza una exepción aritmetica, ya que los numeros se pueden multiplicar por 0 pero no dividir

Comment: @Federico teoricamente es multiplo de todos, en este caso creo que es mejor validar y en caso que se requiera poner una observacion

Comment: No debería aceptar números con coma como 5.3

Comment: En general, `numero` debe ser un número natural, por lo que primero debe comprobar si la entrada es correcta. Esta haciendo un parseInt, con lo que en principio faltaría comprobar que es > 0, ya que podría meter números negativos. Luego el nivel de matemáticas que pida es otra cosa.

Comment: El número `0` es múltiplo de 5 y todos los números son múltiplo de `0`. No debería estar esa primera condición donde valida que sea mayor a `0`.

Answer (score 7):

El operador `%` devuelve **el resto de la división entera**, y todo valor numérico distinto de `0` se considera *verdadero*, por lo tanto, basta con **darle la vuelta** a tu `if( )`:

```
let numero = parseInt( prompt( "Ingrese un numero por favor: " ) );

if( numero % 5 ) {
  console.log( "No, el número " + numero + " no es múltiplo de 5" );
} else {
  console.log( "Si, el número " + numero + " es múltiplo de 5" );
}
```

Simplemente, lo tenías *del revés* :-)

Answer (score 1):

Se puede crear una función llamada `es_múltiplo_de_5`, la cual recibe el parámetro `número`, y retorna un texto formado por varias partes, afirmando o negando su multiplicidad.

```
texto_1+", el número "+número+texto_2+" es múltiplo de 5."
```

Primero se declara en una variable la condición, es decir, su resto `número%5`, en *JavaScript* es verdadero mientras sea diferente de *0*. Si el número es *0* es verdadero, es decir, es múltiplo, si el número es *0.1* ya no es múltiplo. Vuelve a ser múltiplo en *5*, o *5.0*, o *10*, o incluso es aceptable números muy próximos debido a la falta de precisión, como por ejemplo *10.0000000000000003*, la computadora transforma los bytes `1`, `0`, `0`, `0`, `0` en algo cuantificable en binario y por eso es aceptable números cercanos al entero, puede tener muchos *9* después de la coma y seguir siendo aceptable.

Las partes del texto se declaran en variables separadas, `texto_1` y `texto_2`. Si el resto es mayor a cero, se escribe `"No"` en el primero y un `" no"` en el segundo con letras en minúscula y un espacio al principio. Si es exactamente *0*, un `"Sí"` en el primer texto, en mi caso prefiero incluir la tilde `í`, y en el segundo solo un texto vacío, `""`.

Para analizar cualquier número, el `parseInt` no lo uso, directamente analizo el número que venga.

En vez del `prompt`, prefiero usar un `input` en *HTML*, y a medida que vas presionando teclas, el `onkeyup` llama a una función que muestre en consola el múltiplo mediante `console.log`, pero se puede hacer de las dos maneras.

Código:

```js
function es_múltiplo_de_5(número){
  let condición = número%5
  let texto_1 = (condición?"No":"Sí")
  let texto_2 = (condición?" no":"")
  return texto_1+", el número "+número+texto_2+" es múltiplo de 5."
}
function mostrar_múltiplo(){
  console.log(es_múltiplo_de_5(document.querySelector("input").value))
}
```

```html
Ingrese un número por favor: <input onkeyup="mostrar_múltiplo()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Sólo te faltó igualar el 5 con el 0.

```js
let numero = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un numero por favor: "));

if(numero % 5 == 0) {
    console.log("Si, el número " + numero + " es múltiplo de 5");
} else {
    console.log("No, el número " + numero + " no es múltiplo de 5");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let numero = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un numero por favor:"));

numero > 0 && numero % 5 == 0 ? console.log("Si, el número "+numero+ " es múltiplo de 5") : console.log("No, el número "+numero+ " no es múltiplo de 5");
```